# Selenium Python -- this is not duplicate question..actually not able to locate element properly

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

I have below program to take screenshot via selenium

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Downloadsnew\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.maximize_window()
    #driver.implicitly_wait(40)
    driver.get("https://now.com/welcome.do")
    #element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.id,'user_name')))
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("user_name")
    elem.send_keys("user1")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")
    elem.send_keys("password1")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    elem.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.url_changes(driver.current_url))
    element=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presenceOfElementLocated((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='sn-widget-list-title'][contains(.,'Dashboards')]"))).click()
   print(element)
```

When i execute it should login  with user name and password , and then it will open another page, then I need to click on a link where it says dashboard.

Now what happens is it login sucessfully , then after going to main page, its throwing below error

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
```

so I am not sure which element it was saying stale and its dashboard click is not working... can some one suggest what is wrong...so I used one chrome extension called truepath to know exact xpath for that Dashboard link...it said like

```
//div[@class='sn-widget-list-title'][contains(.,'Dashboards')]
```

When I another tool called Element locator, then I got xpath as below

```
//*[@id="b9169d55873212001ac119fa84e3ece3"]/div[1]/div[1]
```

When I do normal inspect on that dashboard link then do a copy of selector and xpath I get like this:

//*[@id="b9169d55873212001ac119fa84e3ece3"]/div/div

css selector:

```
#b9169d55873212001ac119fa84e3ece3 > div > div
```

This is html inspect for that dashboard

[image]

I tried all above for locating that element and then click but not working any suggestions please.

Comment: Hi, i verified those two links for which my question was marked for duplicate, but that solution did not work :(

Comment: one more thing i need to mention that dashboard link is within scroll bar..do I need to execute specific command to find dashboard link with in that scrollbar ..

Comment: I would recommend to use full xpath, because of ID looks like its generated to avoid unexperienced web scrapers to scrap their website :) Hope it helps

Comment: @DebanjanB, I know that you are experienced, but still, you should atleast be helpful, when a person says that THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE, but you still mark it as one ....  if you do, write him atleast a comment with a small explanation, it wont kill you // have a great day

Comment: @StyleZ I had no clue about the previous three comments as it seems I wasn't marked in any of those. Afterall 1) Title reading as `Selenium Python — this is not duplicate question..actually not able to locate element properly` neither seems to be a well researched question nor it fits our community standards . 2) OP haven't mentioned about his/her research. 3) As a canonical duplicate target was provided OP didn't turn up to edit the question to demonstrate how this question was different from the duplicate target. Hope that clears all the doubts.

Comment: Dear All, First thing to clarify since the mentioned suggested posts did not solve my probelm.. If you still some one feel that is duplicate, then i am sorry. I swear i made all attempts to solve the issue on my own, but struck at some point hence reaching out to experts here. No one perfect int his world, may be i did not post it correctly, but genuinely I have made attempts solve the problem on my own. So now glad to say I figured out the issue and solved my self. Thanks @StyleZ for your suggestions about full Xpath, that made way for my solution